# How to avoid linebreak in Safari?

Tags: css, wordpress

I am using cforms plugin on a wordpress page.

Unfortunately "required" in Russian seems to be two words according to the translation office.

In Firefox it looks ok, in Safari it breaks to the bottom left of that line.

```
span.reqtxt,
span.emailreqtxt { 
 margin:2px 0 0 3px;
 font-size:0.9em;
  font-weight:bold;
  color:#0d5f99;
 display: -moz-inline-box; 
 vertical-align:top;
}
```

[image]

How to fix this? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Safari of course won't recognize "display: -moz-inline-box;". Both Firefox and Safari will accept "display: inline-box;" without a vendor prefix. That should fix it.